# Confused by profit and loss

Tags: pine-script

My strategy is for cryptocurrencies and I used to have these orders until now. I wanted to add profit target and stop loss, which means I have to use `strategy.exit`.

```
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = buyCondition)
strategy.close("Buy", when = sellCondition)
```

How are the profit and loss calculated? All I want is buy price + custom %. In other words, `profit = buy price * (1 + (5 / 100))`. Same for stop loss, `loss = buy price * (1 - (5 / 100))`. Or simply to calculate it based on `close + syminfo.mintick` or whatever that way was. I just don't want numbers like 55000, look below.

```
strategy.exit("Custom sell", "Buy", profit = 55000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code it like this: (in this example TP and SL are set to 5% each
First you set up these lines:

```
// Stop Loss settings
StopLossPercent = input(5, title="Stop Loss", minval=0.01, step=0.5)
StopLoss = (close * (StopLossPercent / 100)) / syminfo.mintick

// Take Profit settings
TakeProfitPercent = input(5, title=" Take Profit", minval=0.01, step=0.5)
TakeProfit = (close * (TakeProfitPercent / 100)) / syminfo.mintick
```

Then for your strategy, you write this line below your strategy.entry

`strategy.exit("Stop Loss or Take Profit", loss = StopLoss, profit = TakeProfit)`